# write png images into PDF using c# for windows 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8.1

I am able to insert jpeg image base64 into PDf using DCTDecode

```
 public static string GetImageXObj(int position, string imgName, int imgOriginalWidth, int imgOriginalHeight, string encodedimage)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} 0 obj", position));
        str.AppendLine("<<");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("  /Name /{0}", imgName));
        str.AppendLine("  /Type/XObject");
        str.AppendLine("  /Subtype/Image");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("  /Width {0}", imgOriginalWidth));//original img width
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("  /Height {0}", imgOriginalHeight));//original img height
        str.AppendLine("  /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB");
        str.AppendLine("  /BitsPerComponent 8");
        str.AppendLine("  /Filter /DCTDecode ");

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("  /Length {0}", encodedimage.Length));
        str.AppendLine(">>");
        str.AppendLine("stream");
        str.AppendLine(encodedimage);
        str.AppendLine("endstream");
        str.AppendLine("endobj");
        return str.ToString();
    }
    async void GeneratePDFMethod(StorageFile file)
    {
        var fileBytes1 = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);//base64 is the image base64 string

        var fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(fileBytes1, 0, fileBytes1.Length);//GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
                                                                                                                        //var fileBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes1, 0, fileBytes1.Length);
        using (var stream = await System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))//.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))//System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))                   

            {
//some code related to pdf headers
                writer.WriteLine(PdfUtilities.GetImageXObj(8, "I1", 640, 359, fileBytes));
//some code related to pdf trailor 
            }
        }
    }
```

The output for the above method is as shown below

```
8 0 obj
<<
/Name /Im
/Type/XObject
/Subtype/Image
/Width 500
/Height 400
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /DCTDecode
/Length 1209
>>
stream
//base64 string
endstream
endobj
```

But when I tried to insert PNG images base64 string into pdf using FlatDecode,I was unable to insert into PDF.

I have used c# for writing into PDF.

Please let me know how to insert png images into PDF..

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and what issue you are having. Take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins : when i use jpeg image base64 string, pdf file is getting created and i am able to see the jpeg image got rendered in PDF file...but when i pass png image base64 in this case also pdf file is getting created when i open the file i am getting out of memory(the png file i used is only of size 17.9 kb)

Comment: I recommend reading first the PDF specification.

Comment: @iPDFdev: I have gone through PDF Specifications its mentioned like need to use some predictor functions for png images..i am unable to get that for windows 8.1 c# can you please help me out on that with some code snippet..

Comment: @SandeepBhaskara PDF does not support PNG. When embedding a PNG into PDF, you have to transform your image data into a format supported by PDF. If you want code samples, simply look into some open source PDF libraries. If you want to *use* that code, consider the license your source library has been published under.

Comment: @mkl: i haven't found any open source PDF libraries for windows 8.1 C#, can you please share the open source PDF library links for WinRT. one more thing is if i transform the png into the format supported by PDF then the image will loose its transparecny right?then how to overcome that?

Comment: *"i haven't found any open source PDF libraries for windows 8.1 C#, can you please share the open source PDF library links for WinRT."* - there are multiple ones, e.g. iText for .Net, PdfSharp, PdfClown, PDFBox for .Net. And as you only are looking for source code to transform PNGs to a PDF bitmap format, it does not matter whether or not the library works on Windows 8.1/WinRT; as long as it is C# (or even Java), it should be trivial to port.

Comment: *"one more thing is if i transform the png into the format supported by PDF then the image will loose its transparecny right?then how to overcome that?"* - as @iPDFdev already recommended, read the PDF specification, especially the section on "Masked Images" - here multiple ways to use transparency in images are specified.

Comment: @mkl: Please can you help me out on this.. what are the changes i have to do in the above code if it is png base64 string to make my code to work?

Comment: Please do follow the hint and look what existing open source PDF libraries do. But it will be more complicated, or at least more cumbersome than your code for JPEG images.

Comment: That been said, you should definitely change one major aspect of your code: You appear to build the PDF in a character string. IMO this is a very bad idea because it implies an insane memory overhead and also comes with the danger of methods built for *text* (character strings) processing applying unwanted changes to your *binary* data (PDF is a binary format). I see you using `string.Format` to write integer PDF number objects; `string.Format` by default is using the conventions of the current culture. So, if you do the same for float PDF number objects, your code will fail in some cultures.

Comment: @mkl: Thanks for reply

Comment: @mkl: "you appear to build the PDF in a character string. IMO this is a very bad idea because it implies an insane memory overhead and also comes with the danger of methods built for text (character strings) processing applying unwanted changes to your binary data (PDF is a binary format).".. what is the best method then?

Comment: PDF is a binary format, so PDF files should be generated in instances of `byte[]`, `ByteBuffer`, `OutputStream`, or comparable classes. One might consider creating small sections (instructions in content streams, object numbers, ...) in Strings first (as they are specified using the ASCII codes of the constituting characters), but then they should quickly be translated to `byte` sequences and added to a structure as described above. Before doing that one can model certain structures as Java objects but early serialization to bytes can lessen the memory impact, in particular when streaming...